# Django admin : Removing default links

Tags: django, django-admin

In django admin the database has one of its columns always displayed as a link. How can we avoid getting the link on these elements that django gives us by default?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **list_display_links** to change the columns you want to be displayed as links.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: even though i have not placed the field in the list_display_links it is still displayed as link.How to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class WhateverAdmin(django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin):

   def filtered_url_filed(self):
      return '' if self.url_field == self.url_filed.default else self.url_field

   list_display(...
                'filtered_url_field',
                ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you want to display list without any links?  If so then you can't do it without some dirty hack.  Here is an example of how to cheat the django admin:

```
class CheatListDisplayLinks(list):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.extend(args)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        if item == 'cheat_field':
            return True
        return super(CheatListDisplayLinks, self).__contains__(item)

class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = CheatListDisplayLinks('name', 'last_updated')
    list_display_links = ['cheat_field']
```